# MySQL page view counter ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up a page view counter that will insert if no entry exists or update if it does and increment the value. Below is the query, however it creates a new entry every time and doesn't increment. Not sure what I have wrong here?

`$query = "INSERT INTO views (item, item_id, views) VALUES ('profile', {$usr['user_id']}, views = views + 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE item = 'profile', item_id = {$usr['user_id']} ";`

This is the table structure:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a unique index on one of the columns you're inserting? If not, MySQL has no way to detect a duplicate.

Comment: yes I do - is that the only way to detect a unique entry? I figured the combination of item + item_id counts as unique identifier ?

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` query, along with any indexes you create separately?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not 100% sure what im doing. I included an image of the table structure in the post. Is that what you wanted? Basically I'd like to count views on a series of pages. Each one will have a `item` like 'profile', 'page1' etc and an associated unique id for that `item`.

Comment: `item` + `item_id` may well be unique, but unless you tell MySQL that you want that to be the case it won't know. You haven't posted details of your indexes, but I suspect you need to create a unique index on those columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your SQL is not correct, do as below

```
$query = "INSERT INTO views (item, item_id, views) VALUES ('profile', {$usr['user_id']}, views + 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views = views + 1 ";
```

Comment: Thank you, however that is still making a new entry every time I refresh the page? Not updating the existing entry

Comment: refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: need one unique key in SQL